# Why is Conga Queries inserting http:// in my query?

Tags: conga

I have a Conga query that used to work, but is not working now that looks like so:

> SELECT Description, SUM(Quantity)  FROM OrderItem  WHERE
>   Order.Account.Id = '{pv0}' AND
>   (PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Group__c = 'Used Refrigerant' OR
>   PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Type__c = 'LOS') AND
>   Order.Exclude_From_JSR__c = False AND Exclude_From_JSR__c = False AND
>   PricebookEntry.Product2.Exclude_From_JSR__c = False AND Order.Type =
>   'Contractor' AND (Order.Status = 'Complete' OR Order.Status = 'Send to
>   ERP') AND Order.EndDate>={pv1} AND Order.EndDate<={pv2} GROUP BY
>   Description

When I went to look at it today, in the details page of the query, it is showing http:// in front of Order.Account.Id in the first line and appears to be a hyperlink.  I'm wondering if anyone has seen this before or why it might be doing this?

[image: When editing the SOQL Select Statement field]

[image: When displaying the SOQL Select Statement field]

Answer (score 3):

The reason why is that `order.account.id` looks like a website URL, so it's "helpfully" being converted to a URL. I'm not sure if it's because of the type of field or some other reason, but I have a solution: use `order.accountid` instead of `order.account.id`. They mean the same thing, but it probably won't turn into a URL automatically. As for fixing this bug, you'll want to report it to Conga to see if they can do something about it.

Comment: ah!  That makes sense now.  I noticed it's doing this in other Conga queries that are working on the report, so I don't believe this is the source of my issue.  Thanks for solving the mystery though of why it would do this.

Comment: .id is the TLD for Indonesia. It is entirely possible that Conga is trying to detect real TLDs..... i'd be curious to see if it still fails if you did Order.Account.Name or similar.

Comment: @SebastianKessel Yeah, I don't have Conga to test with, but I'd still be trying to reach their support to see if it's a bug.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'll be wiling to bet some good money that it's a bug. Dying to see the facepalm of whatever dev came up with that idea.

Answer (score 2):

We are experiencing a similar issue that does not involve Conga at all.  Contacted SF support about it and they pointed us to this known issue:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mDRyQAM